# How do I dynamically display an icon for each category with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, dynamic, switch-statement

I am trying to set a different icon for each category I fetch from an API. But the icons I get them from my local pc. 
This is probably not the best way to do it, do you have any other idea?
The props.icon gives me the Object.keys from this API URL: 
https://www.ifixit.com/api/2.0/categories

I tried to use switch statement to dynamically change the src="" from my image but for some reasons doesnt work.

```
//This is how I import the images
import apparelIcon from '../../../assets/img/icons/apparel.png';
import macIcon from '../../../assets/img/icons/mac.png';
import carsIcon from '../../../assets/img/icons/cars.png';


//This is how I try to display it 
const Category = (props) => {
 let icon = null;
 switch (props.icon){ 
     case 'Apparel' : icon = apparelIcon;
     break;
     case 'Mac' : icon = macIcon;
     break;
     case 'Cars' : icon = carsIcon;
     break;   
}

 return (
  <div className={classes.Category}>
     <img src={icon}/>
     <h1>{props.name}</h1>
  </div>
 )
}

export default Category;
```

I don't get any image at all

Comment: Can you show us what the Parent component for Category looks like? You're probably just passing the props incorrectly.

Comment: I published a library for react that might be of use for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-floco

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you must put the logic on the component life cycle with the useEffect. I imagine a state like that:

```
const Category = (props) => {
const [icon, setIcon] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  const setIcon = () => {
     if(props.icon === 'Apparel'){
       setIcon({icon: Apparel})
    } /* rest of the logic */
} setIcon()
}, [props.icon]);
```

i don't think so that its must work, but is convenient try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create index.js in your icons directory and export your images:

```
export { default as ApparelIcon } from './apparel.png';
export { default as MacIcon } from './mac.png';
export { default as CarsIcon } from './cars.png';
```

Then in your code you can import them as an object and get image by dynamic key:

```
import * as icons from '../../../assets/img/icons/';

const Category = (props) => {
 const icon = icons[`${props.icon}Icon`];
 return (
  <div className={classes.Category}>
     <img src={icon}/>
     <h1>{props.name}</h1>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another component which uses an enum to select the appropriate icon.

```
export default function Icon({iconName}){
    return (
        <span className="panel-icon">
            {
                {
                    apparel: <img src='../../../assets/img/icons/apparel.png'/>,
                    mac: <img src='../../../assets/img/icons/mac.png'/>,
                    cars: <img src='../../../assets/img/icons/cars.png'/>,
                }[iconName]
        }
        </span>
    );
}
```

And then where you want it:

```
<Icon iconName={iconName}></Icon>
```